# Current sysdate and time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

First, I am from India and am working for US customers so I am using US(America) database.
 I have tried to display current Sysdate and time but it's showing US time. but I want to display Indian current time.

select sysdate from dual;

Comment: use `CURRENT_DATE`,`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the current date in the session time zone
`sysdate and systimestamp` return date in system(server) timezone

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR

(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"

FROM DUAL;

  NOW
-------------------
04-13-2001 09:45:51
```

Comment: Its showing US time, I want to display time based on time Zone

Comment: SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your system time to Indian time zone. I think this should work.

Also try to change the your session time_zoe

ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta';

Comment: Typically as database developer you don't have access to change timezone on DB operation server.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit this will only change for the current user session, I believe that much access we do give to users generally.

Comment: In your session you can do what you want, of course. But advise was "change your **system** time" - that might be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope it helps

```
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3958062
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions117.htm#SQLRF00671
```

The following example illustrates that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is sensitive to the session time zone:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-5:0';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

SESSIONTIMEZONE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
--------------- ---------------------------------------------------
-05:00          04-APR-00 01.17.56.917550 PM -05:00

ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-8:0';
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

SESSIONTIMEZONE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
--------------- ----------------------------------------------------
-08:00          04-APR-00 10.18.21.366065 AM -08:00
```